# Hide something when mouse scroll

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mousewheel

I'm using onePageNav plugin in my single page website. So I would like to hide menu (#nav) and logo when the page is scrolling. To this, I added the mousewheel plugin. My complete script is look like this:

```
$('#nav').onePageNav({
currentClass: 'current',
    //changeHash: true,
    scrollSpeed: 750,
    scrollOffset: 0,
    scrollThreshold: 0.5,
    easing: 'swing',
    begin: function(){
        hideSubmenu();
    },
    end: function() {
        //verificar se item possui submenu e abrí-lo
        if($('.current').has('ul')){
            $('.current').children('ul').slideDown('slow');
        }
        if($('.current').find('a').attr('href') == "#section-4"){
            $('.sublogo').addClass('sublogo2');
        }else{
            $('.sublogo').removeClass('sublogo2');
        }
        if($('.current').find('a').attr('href') == "#section-3"){
            $('.current').children().find('li').first().addClass('submenu-current');
        }
    },
    scrollChange: function($currentListItem) {
        hideSubmenu();  
        if($currentListItem.has('ul')){
            $('.current').children('ul').slideDown('slow');
        }
        if($currentListItem.find('a').attr('href') == "#section-4"){
            $('.sublogo').addClass('sublogo2');
        }else{
            $('.sublogo').removeClass('sublogo2');
        }
        if($currentListItem.find('a').attr('href') == "#section-3"){
            if ($('#multimidia-fotos-galeria-wrapper').is(':visible')){
                $('.current').children().find('li').first().addClass('submenu-current');
            }
        }

        $("body").mousewheel(function() {
            console.log('scroll');
            $('.sublogo').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#nav').animate({'opacity' : 0}, 200);
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
            $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {
                $('#nav').animate({'opacity' : 1}, 200);
                if($currentListItem.find('a').attr('href') != "#section-1"){
                    $('.sublogo').fadeTo('fast', 1);
                }
            }, 1000));
        });

    }
});
```

I can't use fadeIn() to hide the menu because it interfered with the slide of submenus.

The problem is that the menu behavior is strange: It becomes invisible when the scroll is activated, but it takes time to become visible again.